# Wordpress - External developer added these page folders - How do I move a page from one folder to another folder?

Tags: wordpress, directory, categories

[Picture of our WP Admin Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si0gy.png)

First question - Are these considered "taxonimies"?

An external developer for the company I work at added these folders to our Wordpress. "New Landing Pages" is a group of pages that technically aren't publicly accessible. I've built a page under this "New Landing Pages" folder and I want to transfer it to the "Pages" folder, which is the part of our Wordpress that is accessible to anyone. Is there anyway to do this seamlessly?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow!

What you are referring to are called Post Types, not folders. Whether you can move pages from one post type to another depends on whether they have similar fields.

You can try to do it with this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/

A description on how to use the plugin is found here:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-convert-post-types/

Comment: Thank you, that plugin did exactly what was needed!